# P5.js: how to prevent text from being crushed when using flexbox

Tags: canvas, flexbox, responsive, p5.js, typography

I'm trying to create a responsive web page with p5.js sketch.

In the web page, I toggled a sidebar using flexbox.
But once the sidebar appears at left of the window, it will crush my canvas in p5.js (the consequence of that is all the images/text in the canvas will be deformed as well).
To make my question intelligible, I upload here a image and a [demo](https://codepen.io/waningjupiter/pen/ExWBWMq) Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your helps.

[image: demo_image]

```js
/*When button clicked, show / hide the sidebar */
function toggle(){
  $('main').on('click', '.toggle-sidebar', function(){
    var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
       sidebar.toggleClass('is-visible');
       sidebar.toggle(300);
    })
};
toggle();


/*p5.js*/
const typo = (sketch) => {
  let x1 = 0;
  let x2;
  let speed = 3;
  /*Responsive canvas => make the canvas width equals to it's parent container*/
  let cvs_parent_width = document.getElementById("canvas").offsetWidth;
  let cvs_width = cvs_parent_width;
  /*Responsive font => font size is set based on canvas width */
  let ratio_responsive = 200 / 1500;
  
  sketch.setup = () => {
   let cvs = sketch.createCanvas(cvs_width, sketch.windowHeight);
    sketch.textFont("Palatino");
    cvs.style("display", "block");
  };

  sketch.draw = () => {
    sketch.background(220);
    x1 += speed;
    x2 += speed;
    if (x2 > 0) {
      x1 = x2 - cvs_width;
    }
    if (x1 > 0) {
      x2 = x1 - cvs_width;
    }

    let typo_size = cvs_width * ratio_responsive;
    sketch.textSize(typo_size);
    sketch.text("TYPO CRUSHED", x1, 30, cvs_width, sketch.windowHeight);
    sketch.text("TYPO CRUSHED", x2, 30, cvs_width, sketch.windowHeight);
  }
}

let typo_sketch = new p5(typo, "canvas");
```

```css
html, body  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main{
  overflow:hidden;
}

/* Flexbox for showing n hide sidebar*/
/* flex parent */
.flexgroup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* flex item1 */
.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width:50vw;
}

/* flex item2 */
.image {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
  transition: flex-basis .3s;
}

.none{
  display:none;
}

.sidebar.is-visible  ~ .image {
  flex-basis: 0;
  transition: flex-basis .3s;
}

/* parameters of canvas */
canvas{
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  max-width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
  <main>
  <!-- TOGGLE BUTTON-->
  <button class="toggle-sidebar">Toggle</button>

  <!-- FLEXBOX-->
  <div class='flexgroup'>
  <!-- FLEXBOX Item1-->
    <div class="sidebar none">
     <p>
        SIDEBAR
      </p>
    </div>
   
  <!-- FLEXBOX Item2-->
    <div class='image'>
      <div id="canvas">
  <!-- P5.JS-->    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a canvas is resized due to changes in layout the drawing context size is not updated to reflect this. You need to detect the new dimensions and update the canvas size accordingly. When using a full-window canvas, or a canvas that is sized relative to the window size this can be done fairly trivially with the p5.js [windowResized](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/windowResized) function. However because you are sizing your canvas based on flexbox layout for a specific element (animated no less), things are a little more complicated. If you are using a [modern, mainstream web browser](https://caniuse.com/?search=ResizeObserver), then you can use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver). Here's a snippet that demonstrates using ResizeObserver to solve your issue:

```js
/*When button clicked, show / hide the sidebar */
function toggle(){
  $('main').on('click', '.toggle-sidebar', function(){
    var sidebar = $('.sidebar');
       sidebar.toggleClass('is-visible');
       sidebar.toggle(300);
    })
};
toggle();


/*p5.js*/
const typo = (sketch) => {
  let x1 = 0;
  let x2;
  let speed = 3;
  /*Responsive canvas => make the canvas width equals to it's parent container*/
  let cvs_parent_width = document.getElementById("canvas").offsetWidth;
  let cvs_width = cvs_parent_width;
  /*Responsive font => font size is set based on canvas width */
  let ratio_responsive = 200 / 1500;
  let cvs;
  
  sketch.setup = () => {
    cvs = sketch.createCanvas(cvs_width, sketch.windowHeight);
    sketch.textFont("Palatino");
    cvs.style("display", "block");
    new ResizeObserver(canvasParentResized).observe(cvs.parent());
  };
  
  let supressResize = false;
  function canvasParentResized() {
    if (!supressResize) {
      let parent = cvs.parent();
      if (parent && parent.offsetWidth) {
        // console.log('resized');
        supressResize = true;
        cvs_width = cvs_parent_width = parent.offsetWidth;
        sketch.resizeCanvas(cvs_parent_width, sketch.windowHeight);
      } else {
        console.log(parent.offsetWidth);
      }
    } else {
      // Resizing the canvas tiggers the ResizeObserver recursively
      // console.log('supressed');
      supressResize = false;
    }
  }

  sketch.draw = () => {
    sketch.background(220);
    x1 += speed;
    x2 += speed;
    if (x2 > 0) {
      x1 = x2 - cvs_width;
    }
    if (x1 > 0) {
      x2 = x1 - cvs_width;
    }

    let typo_size = cvs_width * ratio_responsive;
    sketch.textSize(typo_size);
    sketch.text("TYPO CRUSHED", x1, 30, cvs_width, sketch.windowHeight);
    sketch.text("TYPO CRUSHED", x2, 30, cvs_width, sketch.windowHeight);
  }
}

let typo_sketch = new p5(typo, "canvas");
```

```css
html, body  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main{
  overflow:hidden;
}

/* Flexbox for showing n hide sidebar*/
/* flex parent */
.flexgroup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

/* flex item1 */
.sidebar {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width:50vw;
}

/* flex item2 */
.image {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
  transition: flex-basis .3s;
}

.none{
  display:none;
}

.sidebar.is-visible  ~ .image {
  flex-basis: 0;
  transition: flex-basis .3s;
}

/* parameters of canvas */
canvas{
  margin:auto;
  display:block;
  max-width: 100%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
  <main>
  <!-- TOGGLE BUTTON-->
  <button class="toggle-sidebar">Toggle</button>

  <!-- FLEXBOX-->
  <div class='flexgroup'>
  <!-- FLEXBOX Item1-->
    <div class="sidebar none">
     <p>
        SIDEBAR
      </p>
    </div>
   
  <!-- FLEXBOX Item2-->
    <div class='image'>
      <div id="canvas">
  <!-- P5.JS-->    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, when the container changed its size, i didn't think of using a resize function for the parent container. Many thanks for the detailed and constructive explanation ! That helped a lot.